# Proving $\gcd(a,a+b) = \gcd(a,b)$ (using Bezout)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to prove that $\gcd(a,a+b) = \gcd(a,b)$ in order to prove that two successive fibonacci numbers are coprime. I want to use Bezout's Identity, would this be correct?

Let  $ \gcd(a, a+b) = x \ ,$ by Bezout's identity we have:
$$ \ ma \ + n(a+b) = x$$
$$(m+n) a + bn = x$$
Now we can say that, *at least*,  $\ x$  divides $a$ and $b$, so $\gcd(a,b) \ge x = \gcd(a,a+b).$

Suppose now that $d = \gcd(a,b) > x = \gcd(a,a+b) $, then we have:
$$a = d\lambda_1,\quad b= d\lambda_2$$
Hence:
$$\gcd(a,a+b) = \gcd (d\lambda_1, d\lambda_1 +d\lambda_2 ) = d \cdot \gcd(\lambda_1, \lambda_1+ \lambda_2)$$

And because $\gcd(\lambda_1, \lambda_1+\lambda_2) \ge 1$ we get that $d = \gcd(a,b) \gt d \cdot \gcd(\lambda_1,\lambda_1+ \lambda_2)$, a contradiction.

So $\gcd(a,a+b) = \gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Compare with the proofs at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/why-gcdb-qbr-gcdb-r-so-gcdb-a-gcdb-a-bmod-b). And yes, two successive Fibonacci terms are coprime, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/prove-that-any-two-consecutive-terms-of-the-fibonacci-sequence-are-relatively-pr). Note that there are several different answers, so you can choose the one you like most.

Comment: As [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2966323/242) in the linked dupe. your equalities imply the set equality $\,a\Bbb Z + (a+b)\Bbb Z = a\Bbb Z + b\Bbb Z,\,$ so the sets have the same least positive elements, i.e. $\gcd(a,a+b) = \gcd(a,b)\,$ by Bezout. This method will be clearer when you learn about *ideals*.